# Looking for a way to fire separate events on two different buttons with same class name in spectrumjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using spectrumjs and when one button is clicked it invokes the code for both buttons. If I could change the class name of one of the buttons the problem would be solved, however the color picker is dynamically generated and I do not know how to reconfigure the code to do this.

Here is what I have:

```
$(".sp-choose").click(function(){
    bgColor = $("#custom").spectrum("get");
    bgColor = bgColor.toHexString();
    canvas.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    canvas.setBackgroundImage();
    canvas.renderAll();
});

$(".sp-choose").click(function() {
    newColor = $("#custom2").spectrum("get");
    newColor = newColor.toHexString();
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = newColor;
    drawColor();
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

When I change the color of the text and click sp-choose button I lose the original background color, because both of these are invoked. This does not happen after initially changing the color, then changing the background color or text color changes correctly. It's mostly after the first change of the text color that I lose the background.

Comment: Attach event once and process your logic inside for two cases

Comment: How is this related to "fabricjs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only two buttons and you don't need *beautiful* solution, you may separate these two by index:

```
$(".sp-choose").eq(0).click(function(){
    bgColor = $("#custom").spectrum("get");
    bgColor = bgColor.toHexString();
    canvas.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    canvas.setBackgroundImage();
    canvas.renderAll();
});

$(".sp-choose").eq(1).click(function() {
    newColor = $("#custom2").spectrum("get");
    newColor = newColor.toHexString();
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = newColor;
    drawColor();
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only two buttons then,

```
$(".sp-choose").click(function (e) {
    if (this == $(".sp-choose")[0]) {
        bgColor = $("#custom").spectrum("get");
        bgColor = bgColor.toHexString();
        canvas.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        canvas.setBackgroundImage();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});

$(".sp-choose").click(function (e) {
    if (this == $(".sp-choose")[1]) {
        newColor = $("#custom2").spectrum("get");
        newColor = newColor.toHexString();
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = newColor;
        drawColor();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Or similar, will work. The first button will run the first function, the second button will run the second function. You could combine both into one function and switch inside there instead.

```
$(".sp-choose").click(function (e) {
    if (this == $(".sp-choose")[0]) {
        bgColor = $("#custom").spectrum("get");
        bgColor = bgColor.toHexString();
        canvas.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        canvas.setBackgroundImage();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

    if (this == $(".sp-choose")[1]) {
        newColor = $("#custom2").spectrum("get");
        newColor = newColor.toHexString();
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = newColor;
        drawColor();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Like so

http://jsfiddle.net/eLdnt1zf/1/